# Capture commit count per pull request in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I would like to get info on the number of commits per pull request. For now, semi-automated would be fine. Just looking for a simple approach, say, a PowerShell script. I'll likely need to create similar types of reports with different data in the future.

Does any approach lend itself to such a quick and dirty approach with Azure DevOps data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special Rest API for this: [Pull Request Commits - Get Pull Request Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20commits/get%20pull%20request%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/commits?api-version=5.1
```

So, simple PowerShell script:

```
$pat = "YOUR-PERSONAL-ACCESS-TOKEN"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,"$pat")))
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/commits?api-version=5.1"

$commitsCount = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $jsonBody -ContentType 'application/json').count
```

Comment: Wow! That is so much simpler than anything I've tried!